# Android: Passing explicit Uri Intent between two apps (No activity found to handle Intent)

Tags: android, android-intent

I know that many similarly phrased questions have been downvoted. However, I have viewed many threads here and several pages on the Android Developer website (including https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-filters.html and https://android-developers.googleblog.com/2009/11/integrating-application-with-intents.html ) and have been unable to work out how to apply the guidance to my situation.

I wish to transfer location data (latitude and longitude) from an app that I am writing to a mapping app that I have written.

The receiving app's package name is `com.prepbgg.mymap` and it's main activity is `.MyMap`. The Manifest includes:

```
<activity android:name=".MyMap"
          android:label="@string/app_name"
          android:configChanges ="orientation" >
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="com.prepbgg.mymap.action.GEO"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <data android:scheme="geo" android:host="mymap.prepbgg.com"/>
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

The main activity (MyMap.java) includes:

```
Intent intent = getIntent();
Uri myMapData = intent.getData();

try {
    Toaster.Toast(myMapData.toString(),"Long");
    Log.i("nba",myMapData.toString());
} catch(Exception e) {
    Toaster.Toast("No data received","Long");
    Log.i("nba","No data received");
}
```

The sending app includes this code:

```
    val btnMyMap = findViewById<ImageButton>(R.id.btnMyMap)
    btnMyMap.setOnClickListener() {
        var mmUriString = "geo:51.3,-0.31" // Lat and Long hard-coded for test purposes
        var mmIntentUri = Uri.parse(mmUriString)
        val mmIntent = Intent("com.prepbgg.mymap.action.GEO",mmIntentUri)
        mmIntent.setPackage("com.prepbgg.mymap")
        startActivity(mmIntent)
    }
```

When I click the relevant button in the sending app it fails with the exception:

```
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: No Activity found to handle Intent { act=com.prepbgg.mymap.action.GEO dat=geo:51.3,-0.31 pkg=com.prepbgg.mymap }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace:

```
<data android:scheme="geo" android:host="mymap.prepbgg.com"/>
```

with:

```
<data android:scheme="geo" />
```

A `geo` `Uri` does not have a host, and you are not using a host in your `Uri`. But, your `<intent-filter>` is mandating a host of `mymap.prepbgg.com`, so your filter does not match the `Intent`.